# Pokemon Go 10k Egg

Tags: pokemon-go

The other day I got a 10k egg and I was pretty hyped seeing as they are quite rare now.    So I decided I would go out and walk 10k.   When the egg got to 9.9k I got out my phone and looked at it then put it back in my pocket.  But then when I checked it again the egg was not there it had disappeared from the page where it shows all the eggs.    So I checked journal.  Nothing.  I went onto Pokemon and clicked recently caught.    Nothing.      I don't know what happend that day but I would like to know.

Comment: FWIW I don't believe Journal shows egg hatching.

Comment: @DasBeasto I had an egg that disappeared on me this morning when it should have hatched. When I look in my journal, it says, "Ekans was hatched!" with the CP and time. So at least in Android version 0.33.0 (installed Aug 7, 2016) it does show it. It might not have before that.

Comment: @rbwhitaker It does for me now as well, I believe that was added in with one of the last two updates but I couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score -2):

It likely hatched and you never got a notification, sort your pokemon by recent and see if there's anything there you don't recognize.

Comment: 'I went to pokemon recently caught. Nothing.' from OP's post